# Is it possible to get via CLI the commercial name (Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks, ...)

Tags: macos, command-line

At the moment I'm using both `uname` and `sw_vers`

```
darwin_version=`uname -r`
osx_version=`sw_vers -productVersion`
```

But if I want to display the commercial name (Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks, ...) I have to manually maintain a list of osx version - commercial name pair.

I'd like to avoid that manual mapping and rely on *system data*. Is it possible ?

Comment: When I see commands like `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` I'm not sure it's really possible.

Comment: Yeah I've looked at `system_profiler` as well, and that got me desperate, that's why I'm asking here. But I fear too it's not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure which way round to close these as duplicates. This was asked well before the newer question, but it looks like the newer one has got all the attention (except from me, I upvoted and am the save on this question, and never saw the new one!). Or should I merge the newer one into this?

Comment: Let's keep this one closed the newer question has more answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you said it : it's a commercial name and it's barely present in the OS it self. It no real wonder, it has no meaning for devs (far less than a version or a build number).

AFAIK It's mentioned in some help pages, but that's almost all.

So until someone would prove me wrong, there is no CLI for that (excluding `curl` stuff, which would imho not be a suitable option here).

Comment: Yes that's what I fear! For the eycandy of my script I'd like to display the commercial name, I'm a bit sad there's isn't a property somewhere for that ;)

Comment: When I see the count of upvotes for your question (mine is included) you're not the only one ;)